# System design - dealing with auto account renewal for users with various timezone in a system

Tags: timezone, system

My database stores the time in GMT format and I have a field to store each user's time zone so when I show the user the time its always their local time no matter where they are.

Now the problem is these users get auto renewed for another month of membership when a payment gateway (does not follow GMT) pings my system.

What is the most proper way I can achieve a solution where when the payment gateway pings my system, I renew the user in such a way that it make sense on their time zone? The problem here is if the user's account is set to expire on 5th Jan and its not 5th Jan yet on the user's timezone but its 5th Jan on the server/payment gateway, how do I go about it? I can think of some weird ways to solve this, but I just wanted to know what could be the best possible way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the time zone of the payment system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASSUMING your payment system timezone is fixed (even if it's not GMZ), all you need to do is convert from user timezone to GMT whenever you deal with users, and from GMT to payment system time zone whenever you deal with the payment system.

So your user is PST, your timezone system is EST and you are in England (or at least you're GMT).

User registers for 1 month on 12/31/2010 at 11PM (2300) PST.

PST is GMT - 8 and EST is GMT -5 (or is it -7 and -4... I get ST and DT confused regularly...).

GMT the user registered at 1/1/11 0600 (6 am).
EST the user registered at 1/1/11 0200 (2 am).

As you said, if you told the payment system to expire the user at 1/31/11 at 11pm, it would read that as EST, and send the signal to expire at 2/1/11 4am which would be 1/31/11 8pm PST so the user would lose 3 hours.

But if you tell the payment system to expire the user at 2/1/11 2AM EST, then the signal will be sent at 2/1/11 7am GMT which is 1/31/2011 11PM PST.

So it falls to you to ALWAYS deal with every client, be it user or remote system, in that system's time zone, provided the remote site doesn't support GMT.